# Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Hi I'm using a script for power shell this is part of it where the error is happening: it was working fine until i added the auto file naming by date so I guess the issue is here. any help is appreciated.

```
  foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
  {
    #Write the Header to "Tab Separated Text File"
    "$($web.title) `t $($web.URL) `t  `t  `t `t " | out-file "c:\users_PermisionReport + (date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + "-DSR.csv" -append
     #Get all Groups and Iterate through   
     foreach ($group in $Web.groups)
     {
            "`t  `t $($Group.Name) `t   `t `t " | out-file "c:\users_PermisionReport + (date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + "-DSR.csv" -append
            #Iterate through Each User in the group
                   foreach ($user in $group.users)
                    {
                       #Exclude Built-in User Accounts
                if(($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\authenticated users") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "sharepoint\system") -and ($User.LoginName.ToLower() -ne "nt authority\local service"))
                {
                            "`t  `t  `t  $($user.LoginName)  `t  $($user.name) `t  $($user.Email)" | out-file "c:\users_PermisionReport" + (date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + "-DSR.csv" -append 
}
}
}
}//Error is here.
```

#error message:

```
 Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
 CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
 FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: With this source-code formatting, I'm not surprised that it's hard to spot the error. Please format the code in your question properly, in the course of which you may spot the error yourself. Note that one of the standard reasons for closure of a question is: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."

Comment: This is basically a typo question which is likely to be closed. You would be able to find this yourself if you followed some coding guidelines for blocks https://poshcode.gitbooks.io/powershell-practice-and-style/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.html

Comment: if it is a typo please point it out as far as formatting I clearly pointed out the error. However, I just changed the date appending to the file name line and it worked fine thank you for not helping Matt and mklemnt.

Comment: Yes, I can see where the error is. What I am saying is that if you followed some code guidelines, specifically when it comes to blocks, then you would know you likely have an extra brace in there. In order to fix this you need to line up your closing and opening braces. It doesnt make for a great question since it boils down to a  typo. I am trying to empower you to fix it yourself. You also have unclosed strings in there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any line that contains this code:

```
"c:\users_PermisionReport" + (date -f yyyy-MM-dd) + "-DSR.csv"
```

## Replace it with this code:

```
"c:\users_PermisionReport $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"
```

This will append a date to file name to avoid duplication or deleting the older file. 
this took care of the error with out changing anything else.

Comment: I'd use `("c:\users_PermisionReport {0:yyyy-MM-dd}-DSR.csv" -f (get-date))` But that is a matter of taste/personal preference and is off topic.